# How to check if ANY app is playing any type of media on Android device?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a remote control for integration between Android TV devices and Smartthings Hub. I want to be able to check if any media app is playing anything on the device (Android TV).
If for example, Youtube or Plex app is playing any movie, then I will show the user "playing" , if no app is playing anything , I will display "stopped"

if any type of media (audio or video) is playing, I have to understand this.

I wanted to engage Android mediaplayer with following code, but it did not work:

```
            final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
            if(player.isPlaying()) {
                response.send("playing");
            }
            else {
                response.send("stopped");
            }
```

I am not sure if this instance will attach to the active media player and I couldn't find the correct way. What am I missing ?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `AudioManager` for sound , check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMusicActive())

```
AudioManager.isMusicActive();
```

and for video , The [**SurfaceFlinger**](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/arch-sf-hwc) process can know that it is receiving frames at a consistent rate, but it can't know if it's a video or just app animation.

The mediaserver process is responsible for managing the hardware video decoders. It can know if a video is being decoded, but it can't know if the video is being displayed. It won't be involved if the app is using a custom software-only decoder.

There isn't an unequivocal way to detect that a video is being played and presented on the display.

Comment: I am not interested if it is a video or audio. So if I check Audiomanager and if isMusicActive is true, does that mean either audio or video is being played ? (if we assume each video has sound) I mean, would isMusicActive be true when video with sound is being played ?

Comment: Well, video does not imply audio. Dashcam footage, for example, might be video-only. Moreover,video is a purely foreground thing. so isMusicActive() will return true for other audio apps, and that's why  i suggest you surfaceFlinger

Comment: I tried audiomanager solution. It works. And since I am dealing with Android TV, most of the time media means audio+video. If there is a silent video case, it will be an exception. Thanks.

Comment: btw, I've also checked SurfaceFlinger  as you suggested but couldn't find much information or example usage for it. Do you know where I can  find usage examples ?

Comment: check this link , it may help you : https://www.bradcypert.com/what-is-androids-surfaceflinger/